# Room Database Class in Java and Instantiating in a Kotlin activity

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin, android-room

Just wondering if there is a way to instantiate my Room Database(written in Java) in my `CreateNotesActivity` which is written in Kotlin.

My **DAO** interface and **Entity** class is also written in Java.

My Database class

```
@Database(entities = Note.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NotesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static NotesDatabase notesDatabase;

    public static synchronized NotesDatabase getDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if(notesDatabase == null){
            Room.databaseBuilder(context
            ,NotesDatabase.class,
                    "note_db"
                    ).build();
        }
        return notesDatabase;
    }

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao(); 
}
```

I need to instantiate this in a Kotlin class.

Comment: NotesDatabase is package-private, make it public

Answer (score 0):

After making your getDatabase public Maybe this would help you:

```
        /**
         * Create a new instance of user database
         */
        val dataBase: UserDatabase = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        roomDao = dataBase.roomDao()
```